# Как задать цвет фона на странице только в мобильной версии сайта?

Tags: html, css, html5

хочу чтобы фон сайта на компьютере был белого цвета, а на телефона синего, прописываю следующий код в style.css, но не помогает:

```
body {
    min-width:240px;
background:#1889DB;
    max-width:650px;
```

}

Прошу помочь пожалуйста

Comment: Какой css нужно задать чтобы изменить цвет фона только в мобильной версии сайта

Comment: [@media](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/@media)

Comment: `min-width` и `max-width` используются не для того, для чего Вы подумали. Они просто ограничивают максимальную и минимальную ширину элемента соответственно, так что оно и не поможет.

Comment: А @media просто перед body вставить ?

Comment: Там же [примеры](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/@media#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B) есть, с Вашим же `body`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно использовать media запросы
Пример:

```
 body{
  background:red; 
 }

@media(max-width: 650px){
   body{
       background:#1889DB; 
     }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!